# Can you use field alias with space in Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

We need to create descriptive aliases for fields. Ideally we would like to create views with alias with a space. Is this possible? How can we do this?

Example: 
SELECT word, word_count **"Word Count"** FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] LIMIT 1000

Answer (score 24):

No, the rules for field names (and aliases) in BigQuery are quite simple, and I quote:

> Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with
>   a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

As you see, spaces, quote characters, and other punctuation, are not allowed.  Feel free to open a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/ (explaining your use case, esp. why using underscores in lieu of spaces is not acceptable) -- or star an existing FR at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list if it coincides with your requirements.

Comment: could you reference that quote please?

Comment: If you put with `` and click run, you get a pop-up with this message: Invalid field name "Word Count". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

Comment: @Alex Martelli is there a plan to get the support added for spaces in Alias. Looks in BigQuery editor it validate SQL (syntactically)   but invalid field name error comes while running the SQL ,Semantic analysis it fails

Comment: You can star this feature request to get automatic updates of when this will be supported:
https://issuetracker.google.com/135744916

Answer (score 1):

You can use "`" at the beginning and end of the column name (Word Count)

Answer (score 0):

This is work when you use "`" at the beginning and end of the column name,

for your case :  SELECT word_count as `word count` FROM your_table