# How to use special characters in BigQuery column names?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to use special characters in BigQuery columns but when using it it is throwing error as : **Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "/" at [2:16].**

Query :

```
SELECT *,
buget as budget/bin
 FROM `dummy.book1`
```

Thanks

Comment: to escacpe you need `\` not `/`

Comment: Quotes in sql are " so `as "budget/bin"` should work. Not sure if that holds for BigQuery though

Comment: Hi @nbk can you please elaborate, did not get you.

Comment: It is impossible. **Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 300 characters long.**
Also, here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926175/can-you-use-field-alias-with-space-in-google-big-query

Comment: Hi @Lennart if I am giving "budget/bin" all rows are changed to budget/bin

Comment: Hi @MaxZolotenko yes you are right, seems like not possible in BQ.

Comment: @SandeepMohanty, the quotes are for the name of the resulting column, it should not affect the content. In your case, the column buget is renamed to "budget/bin". But, that is in standard SQL. Other rules may apply for BigQuery

Comment: Example for postgres 14: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3547f998b2ba3cc82e3d1c13b9079de0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. BQ has column name naming [rules](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names) so even when you do `SELECT x AS y`, `y` still has to follow those rules

Comment: Even when quoted?

Comment: Correct.  It works in traditional SQL as you mentioned earlier but while BigQuery does support SQL queries, it does have its own restrictions as well and column naming is one of them.

EDIT: I've also tested it :)